# remove php extension using .htaccess

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

I'm working on script, and want to set links to be as following:

```
www.mysite.com/sign-up.php
to
www.mysite.com/sign-up
```

and

```
www.mysite.com/profile.php?username=abc
to
www.mysite.com/profile/abc
```

I found this code and works for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

but when I want to access:

```
www.mysite.com/profile/abc
```

The stylesheet doesn't work, it seems the path for it has changed. Also all links in that profile become like:

www.mysite.com/profile/**profile**/filename.php

It keeps adding `/profile` everytime

how to fix this?

**EDIT: all files works fine with stylesheet except profile.php**

Comment: "Stylesheet doesn't work" is not problem description. Since this problem is so common, I'll tell you what's the solution - use **absolute** path to your style sheet. You're getting 404 errors because you're using relative ones. Use your browser's developer console to get that information on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create it with [htacess](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/htaccess_redirect) and [modrewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) of apache.

Just check the link below for generating dynamic URL. It might solve your problem:

[URL Generation](http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php)

Comment: thanks that helps me! I may change my links to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Just replace you current rule with this one

Answer (score 0):

`www.mysite.com/sign-up.php` to `www.mysite.com/sign-up`

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [r=301,L]
```

It is required to store this file to folder `www.mysite.com/profile/.htaccess`

```
   RewriteEngine on /profile/
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [r=301,L]
```

`www.mysite.com/profile/abc` to `www.mysite.com/profile/profile.php?username=abc`

The problem is that, first script will redirect `string` to `string.php` so `www.mysite.com/profile/abc` to `www.mysite.com/profile/abc.php` or `www.mysite.com/profile/profile.php?username=abc.php`. We must create an exception:

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [r=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [r=301,L]
```

We can create the whole script as an exception. This will simple do all the work.

Comment: when I access 'http://localhost/adsgate/profile/abc' it redirect me to 'http://localhost/C:/wamp/www/profile.php?username=abc.php/abc' error message 'You don't have permission to access'

Comment: Maybe i found the answer. Last chance.

Comment: still not working, anyway I'll change my links to something else. becuase I have tried so many codes. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem with your rewrite rules, it's a problem with your href's.

If you have a style tag like... `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" media="screen" />` and an a tag like `<a href="profile">`, they will be treated as relative URLs since there is no forward slash at the start. If your browser is at /profile.php, it will load /css/main.css and the link goes to /profile, but once you are at /profile, the browser thinks you are in that "folder", so it will now look at /profile/css/main.css and your link will go to /profile/profile. You need to make the href's absolute paths, i.e. href="/css/main.css" and href="/profile".

Comment: thanks but all the other files works fine with the same style path. only profile.php has the problem

Answer (score 0):

If your CSS link is broken amongst other things, try using the base tag in your document head:

```
<head>
<base href="http://www.mysite.com/" />
</head>
```

I have found this to work when dealing with pesky URL rewrites.

There may be better ways to solve it via .htaccess, but this might be a nice short term fix until that happens.